# Update quantity of a column with combined accounts

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-update, mysql-5.6

Recently there have been changes on how my game server handles user accounts. Previously they used to be separate columns (money, bank, black_money) and now they're all combined under a `accounts` column (pictured below).

I used the run the query `UPDATE users SET money = money + 10000` to give every player an additional amount of money for the money account, but now that they're combined I'm unsure of how to achieve the same result.

[image: picture of column setup]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a `JSON` column with three attributes: money, bank and black_money.

Here is one way to update the value:

```
update users
set accounts = json_object(
    'money', coalesce(accounts ->> '$.money', 0) + 1000,
    'bank',  accounts ->> '$.bank'
    'black_money', accounts ->> '$.black_money'
)
where id = ?
```

Or you can use `jon_set()`, which is probably more efficient than re-creating the whole object (and respects existing keys):

```
update users
set accounts = json_set(
    accounts, 
    '$.money', 
    coalesce(accounts ->> '$.money', 0) + 1000
)
where id = ?
```

Comment: Is there something I am missing here with MySQL version? I tried both snippets you posted and I keep getting an error for MySQL version, specifically line 3 on the first snippet and line 5 on the second. (I'm on version 5.6.49)

Comment: @TimonN: MySQL 5.6 has no JSON support at all - most above functions were added in 5.7. If you want to handle JSON, I would really recommend upgrading...